# 3D coordinates interpolation

Tags: opengl, scenekit

Let's suppose a square (4 points), viewed from top.
Each of the 4 points do not have the same altimetry.

If you look from top (or from bottom), you see a square, but if you look from side, you will see that the 4 points are not at the same level.

So you have a plane which is not horizontal.

Lets imagine a fifth point inside the square. What i want to do is to calculate the altimetry of this fifth point. This altimetry is a function of the position of the point inside the square, and the altimetry of the 4 points of the square.

I think i have to compute an interpolation but i did not managed to do it...

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Unless you know for certain that all points lie on a single plane, you must divide the square up into two triangles. Is this the case for you?

Comment: [Altimetry](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/altimetry) doens't mean what you think it means. The word you're looking for is "height" or "altitude".

Answer (score 1):

So unless you know for certain that all points lie on a single plane, which would be a simplification of this method, I'll assume you have divided your square into two triangles. Furthermore, I'll assume there are 4 vertices, `v_00`, `v_10`, `v_01`, and `v_11` representing each vertex of your square. I will also assume that your triangles are defined as `(v_00, v_10, v_11)`, and `(v_00, v_11, v_01)`.

```
vec4 v00 = vec4(...);
vec4 v01 = vec4(...);
vec4 v10 = vec4(...);
vec4 v11 = vec4(---);

vec4[2][3] triangles = {{v00, v10, v11}, {v00, v11, v01}};
```

Finally, I'll assume you know the X and Y coordinates relative to the bottom left vertex (just subtract the x and y coordinate of your fifth point from the x and y coordinates of `v_00`). I'll call this point P. We'd like to know its z coorinate.

```
vec4 fifthPoint = vec4(...);
vec4 P = fifthPoint - v00;
```

This means the "shared border" of both triangles lies along the diagonal going between the bottom left and top right of your square.

Since both triangles can be entirely different, determining the coordinates of your arbitrary fifth point starts with determining which of the two triangles it is on.

Since we know the shape is a square, we can take the coordinates of our point P relative to `v_00` (as I assumed previously), and see which is greater than the other. If the x coordinate of P is greater than the y coordinate, we know P is on the bottom right triangle. Otherwise it's on the top left one.

```
bool whichTriangle = P.x > P.y;
int triangleIndex = whichTriangle ? 0 : 1;
```

Now that we know which triangle we're on, we can interpolate their coordinates to obtain any point on the surface of the triangle.

For triangle 0:

```
vec4 vectorX = triangles[0][1] - triangles[0][0];
vec4 vectorY = triangles[0][2] - triangles[0][1];
```

For triangle 1:

```
vec4 vectorX = triangles[1][1] - triangles[1][2];
vec4 vectorY = triangles[1][2] - triangles[1][0];
```

Notice that each vector here goes along the x and y axis. That's important, so that we can directly use the x and y coordinates from P to calculate interpolated values.

Next, we normalise the two vectors we just created.

```
vectorX = vectorX.normalize();
vectorY = vectorY.normalize();
```

Now we just need to multiply these two values with the X and Y coordinates of P to get any point on the triangle, and add it to a base point.

For triangle 0:

```
P = triangles[0][0] + vectorX * P.x + vectorY * P.y;
```

For triangle 1:

```
P = triangles[1][1] - vectorX * (1.0 - P.x) - vectorY * (1.0 - P.y);
```

And there you have it. A far too complicated explanation for something that's actually not all that hard. P.z now contains the Z-coordinate of your arbitrary point.

Answer (score 1):

Being a trapezoid ABCD consider this ruled surface:
[image]

Then you can interpolate P1 from A and B, and P2 from C and D. Finally you can interpolate P height from P1 and P2 heights